# How can I add a duration histogram's time data to its bars?

Tags: d3.js

I am working with numerous D3 [duration histograms](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3048166), each with a different duration. I would like to tie in the starting time of the time range each bar represents into a div id inside each bar's HTML. This information would be accessed via jQuery.

Say for example there's a bar at 00:10. I would like to add "00:10" into the bar's div.

What I can't figure out is how to get a hold of these times. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: The bars themselves are not divs, but SVG rectangle elements. I'm a little unsure as to what you would like to achieve. For example, would you like to add a data-time="00:10", which jQuery can read, or a text element which displays the time?

Comment: I would like to add a data-time="00:10", but it would be hidden from sight. I plan on adding a click event to the bar via jQuery to get the data-time, and use it to access an API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add an attribute simply use `selection.attr()` for example:

```
bar.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 1)
    .attr("width", x(data[0].dx) - 1)
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.y); })
    .attr("data-time", function(d){return formatMinutes(d.x)})
```

But, if you simply want to access an API on click, look into d3's `selection.on()`:

```
bar.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 1)
    .attr("width", x(data[0].dx) - 1)
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.y); })
    .on("click", function(d){ 
        accessAPI(formatMinutes(d.x))
    })
```

eg. http://jsfiddle.net/3saQW/

I recommend learning about how d3.js binds data. It may even be that jQuery isn't required. This is a good tutorial series: http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/binding-data/

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough answer!